# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10d33c4a0) to 'UIImage

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, uiimage, firebase-storage

How I represent the image in the firebase storage scored in a node called users with path name pc.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell : viewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "opa", for:indexPath) as! viewTableViewCell

    if let post =  posts[indexPath.row]  {
                    cell.post.text = post

        cell.name.text = self.loggedinuserdata!["name"]  as! String
        cell.handle.text = self.loggedinuserdata!["handle"]  as! String
        cell.pc.image = self.loggedinuserdata!["pc"]  as! UIImage

    }


 return cell

}
```

Thank you in anticipation ))

Comment: `pc` key having value as `String` not `UIImage`

Comment: @NiravD so please how i represent the image  correctly

Comment: I think your pc key contains String. If pc key is string with url then you need to download image from this url and then set it to your imageView.

Comment: @SamiulIslamSami please may u provide any code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    cell.pc.image = UIImage.init(named: self.loggedinuserdata!["pc"] as! String)
```

**If image fetch from url**

```
cell.pc.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.loggedinuserdata!["pc"] as! String), placeholderImage: nil)
```

[SDWebImage Source](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: the error gone but the image view is still blank ((

Comment: is it server url ?

Comment: Invalid HTTP method/URL pair.

Comment: try my updated answer . because it is server url so your need to download image .

Comment: value of type uiimage has no member sd_setimage i have this error

Comment: did you add sdwebimage library to your project ? and check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to write this function and pass url as parameter

```
func downloadImageFromUrl(imageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: UIImage) -> Void) {

                let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                    completion(UIImage(data: data)!)

                }
                task.resume()
}
```

and Call it

```
self.downloadImageFromUrl(imageUrl: self.loggedinuserdata!["pc"] as! String , completion: { image in

        cell.pc.image = image

  })
```

Comment: in cellForRowaAt method you just copy and paste my second code.

Comment: how can i indicate what is happening because the uiimageview is blank?

Comment: Can you give a string from self.loggedinuserdata!["pc"]. I just want to test

Comment: It shows SSL is required to perform this operation.

Comment: Are you fetching this data from Json?